# sorting works manually but not with "onclick" functions

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

I have a list of names that i want to sort by how many points they have, it's by default set to `0` and each time i press a button it adds a point to that specific name, but doesn't rank them to be in the first place, if i add points manually in the `JS` list it works fine but not when i use the buttons. Here is what I tried:

```js
 let characters = [
       {name: document.getElementById("name 1").textContent, points: 0},
       {name: document.getElementById("name 2").textContent, points: 0},
       {name: document.getElementById("name 3").textContent, points: 0}
    ];
        
    function choice (button) {
       const buttonCharacterObject = characters.find(obj => obj.name === button.textContent);
       buttonCharacterObject.points += 1;
       
       console.log(characters)
    }

    const ranking = characters.sort((a, b) => (a.points < b.points ? 1 : -1));
    
    console.log(ranking);
```

```html
    <button id="name 1" onclick="choice(this)">John</button>
    <button id="name 2" onclick="choice(this)">Martin</button>
    <button id="name 3" onclick="choice(this)">Sam</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the ranking in the function as well, and the console outputs the ranked characters.

```js
 let characters = [
       {name: document.getElementById("name 1").textContent, points: 0},
       {name: document.getElementById("name 2").textContent, points: 0},
       {name: document.getElementById("name 3").textContent, points: 0}
    ];
        
    function choice (button) {
       const buttonCharacterObject = characters.find(obj => obj.name === button.textContent);
       buttonCharacterObject.points += 1;
       
    const ranking = characters.sort((a, b) => (a.points < b.points ? 1 : -1));
    
    console.log(ranking);
    }
```

```html
    <button id="name 1" onclick="choice(this)">John</button>
    <button id="name 2" onclick="choice(this)">Martin</button>
    <button id="name 3" onclick="choice(this)">Sam</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort in `choice()` method after you've incremented points.

try following:

```
function choice (button) {
   const buttonCharacterObject = characters.find(obj => obj.name === button.textContent);
   buttonCharacterObject.points += 1;

   characters.sort((a, b) => (a.points < b.points ? 1 : -1));

   console.log(characters)
}
```

Comment: tried it, but console.log(ranking); need to be in the function as well, thank you for the help